# How to speed up this code to find and delete rows if a substring is found

Tags: performance, vba, excel, search

Below code works great as expected the only downside is its slow because I am using this to search for all the instances of the substring and delete the Entire row if found in any cell of the whole workbook.

Aim is simple just delete the entirerow if the entered string is found in any cell string

```
Dim wo As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim I As Long, j As Long, m As Long
Dim toFind As String, testStr As String
Dim pos As Long
Dim lstRow As Long, cutRow As Long
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim Cell As Range

Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Sub SearchDelete()

toFind = InputBox("Enter the substring you want to search for.", "Welcome", "AAAA")
toFind = Trim(toFind)
j = 0

If toFind = "" Then
    MsgBox "Empty String Entered.Exiting Sub Now."
    Exit Sub
Else
        WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

        'Begin the loop.
        For I = 1 To WS_Count

Label1:
                For Each Cell In Worksheets(I).UsedRange.Cells

                    If Trim(Cell.Text) <> "" Then
                        pos = 0
                        pos = InStr(1, Trim(Cell.Text), toFind, vbTextCompare)

                        If pos > 0 Then     'match Found'

                            cutRow = Cell.Row
                            Worksheets(I).Rows(cutRow).EntireRow.Delete
                            j = j + 1
                           GoTo Label1
                        Else: End If

                    Else: End If

                Next Cell
         Next I
End If

MsgBox "Total " & j & " Rows were deleted!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `range.find`? Edit: but this may be more appropriate for code review.

Comment: One really easy speed increase is to use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of your sub and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of your sub. This will only update the screen at the end of your sub rather than every time it deletes a row.

Comment: @findwindow I would do that but I don't know if `Range.Find` will return all the row numbers of the partial matched found and how to use it in loop ? Any example of implementation of that in this case will help me thanks!

Comment: There's `range.findnext`

Comment: @newguy `Range.Find` will find the first instance of whatever you search. `Range.FindNext` will return the next cell that matches and continue to do so until no more cells in the range match the search, at which point it will return `Nothing`

Comment: @Taelsin no, `findnext` will just wrap around to first one found.

Comment: @Taelsin - You are thinking of the situation when you find something and change or delete it. In that case you keep using .FindNext until there is nothing left to be found. In this situation it is better to collect the matches for a single operation so you have to compare each new .FindNext's cell address to the first one found to see when you have looped all the way around and back to the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Individual operations are pretty much always slower than bulk operations and the [Range.Delete method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834641.aspx) is no exception. Collecting the matching rows with a [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) and then performing the removal *en masse* will significantly speed up the operation.

Temporarily suspending certain application environment handlers will also help things along. You do not need [Application.ScreenUpdating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx) active while you are removing rows; only after you have completed the operation.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub searchDelete()
    Dim n As Long, w As Long
    Dim toFind As String, addr As String
    Dim fnd As Range, rng As Range

    toFind = InputBox("Enter the substring you want to search for.", "Welcome", "AAAA")
    toFind = Trim(toFind)

    If Not CBool(Len(toFind)) Then
        MsgBox "Empty String Entered.Exiting Sub Now."
        GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    End If

    'appTGGL bTGGL:=False   'uncomment this line when you have finsihed debugging

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For w = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
            With .Worksheets(w)
                Set fnd = .Cells.Find(what:=toFind, lookat:=xlPart, _
                            after:=.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
                If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = .Rows(fnd.Row)
                    n = n + 1
                    addr = fnd.Address
                    Do
                        If Intersect(fnd, rng) Is Nothing Then
                            n = n + 1
                            Set rng = Union(rng, .Rows(fnd.Row))
                        End If
                        Set fnd = .Cells.FindNext(after:=fnd)
                    Loop Until addr = fnd.Address
                    Debug.Print rng.Address(0, 0)
                    rng.Rows.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next w
    End With

    Debug.Print "Total " & n & " rows were deleted!"

bm_Safe_Exit:
    appTGGL

End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

Comment: Man, now you're making me rethink my architecture. What if the string you're searching is all grouped closely together (within 40 rows of each other in 6000 rows sheet). Is it faster to use `findnext` or can you just `find` then loop from that row forward?

Comment: @findwindow - I'm not sure how it could be positively determined that strings containing a substring were grouped together but assuming that they were then narrowing the rows to look at would speed things up. However, this leads to the possibility that simply determining the smaller region may take as much or more calculation that simply looping through. e.g. Is find (in a forward direction) then find (in a reverse direction) to determine a 'narrowed' scope for further FindNexts faster then simply Find and FindNext? It seems like it is the same if not more processing.

Comment: It's essentially a list in numerical order with each ID all grouped together in blocks so once I find first occurrence, I know the rest are in the following rows. It is precisely trying to determine the region (range) that drives the architecture. It's actually more complex because each block of IDs may need to be divided. Sound like my architecture is good enough ^_^; Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question: `"How to speed up this code to find and delete rows if a substring is found"` is -  **DON'T** repeat the search from the top of the sheet after you found and removed the row!

Comment: Yes I know that for that I introduced a `Goto` statement which basically repeats the process again after deleting. Do you know how to loop the `For Each Cell` loop backwards ? because I don't.