# Excel 2010 find a if a substring is inside a string

Tags: string, excel, substring

I have a GPS and i get the address in excel like this:

**example:**

*"5555 N street city, state, 58585"*

and I want to take this and search a list to see if the Street in the string is in a list of streets so I can label it "Home" or "Best Buy"

```
example Code Not an actual code:

if(list(A1:A999) string is in,C1,write(B1:B999), else (""))
```

**does anyone know how to write this as an actual code?**

```
Code that work but doesn't work for what I'm doing
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(C3,A1,1)),B1,"")
```

[image]
This will work but only if the string in the list is the same as the string your searching by - I need it to be able to see 8888 N street and say home and see 8887 N street and say home

Comment: Study what @jeeped did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265879/how-to-speed-up-this-code-to-find-and-delete-rows-if-a-substring-is-found).

Comment: Do you want vba or a formula?

Comment: I want a formula - I will drive into VBA but I think I just need to find a formula to search for a word in a string from a list

Comment: See also [If string contains word from list, return value adjacent to list value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628660/if-string-contains-word-from-list-return-value-adjacent-to-list-value/33629724#33629724).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$999,MATCH(1,IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$999,C1))),1,0),0)),"")
```

Being an array formula, it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done properly Excel will automatically put `{}` around the formula, indicating an array formula.

[image: ![enter image description here]